# Swift/Mapbox - How to set a camera without knowing the centre coordinate

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

How do I set a camera given an initial coordinate (latitude, longitude), a heading (from 0-360), and an altitude, without knowing the centre coordinate on the map?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could try this, this will create a camera with your coords, heading and distance and will fly to it animated, while centering the camera to the mapview:

```
let latitude = YOUR_LAT
let longitude = YOUR_LONG
let heading = YOUR_HEADING
let pitch = YOUR_PITCH
let fromDistance = YOUR_DISTANCE

let destination = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

let camera = MGLMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: destination, fromDistance: fromDistance, pitch: pitch, heading: heading) 

YOUR_MAPVIEW.setCamera(camera, withDuration: 0.5, animationTimingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)) {

               //code when finished                 

            }
```

Answer (score -1):

For start you need to show any random location and then focus on the point where you want the camera centre will be.

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.8683,
                                              longitude: 151.2086, zoom: 16)
let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
```